# Most efficient way to find nearest match across multiple join table records in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Say you have some records that look like

```
+--------+--------------+-------+
| person | attribute_id | value |
+--------+--------------+-------+
|      1 |            1 |     4 |
|      1 |            2 |     2 |
|      1 |            3 |     0 |
|      2 |            1 |     0 |
|      2 |            2 |     5 |
|      2 |            3 |     5 |
|      3 |            1 |     3 |
|      3 |            2 |     4 |
|      3 |            3 |     1 |
+--------+--------------+-------+
```

If we pivot on person=1, what would be the most efficient way of finding the nearest matching person based on these attribute scores from 0 to 5?

Ideally I'd like to do this within the SQL (MySQL) rather than the app layer.

### Edit for more explanation

I can see this would be much easier to model if you had the schema

```
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|person | attribute_1  | attribute_2 | attribute_3 |
|1      | 4            | 2           | 0           |
|2      | 0            | 5           | 5           |
|3      | 3            | 4           | 1           |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

As you could do something like

`SELECT ABS($search_attr_1-attribute_1) AS diff_1, ABS($search_attr_2-attribute_2) AS diff_2, ABS($search_attr_3-attribute_3) AS diff_3
FROM scores
ORDER BY diff_1 ASC, diff_2 ASC, diff_3 ASC`

Comment: what do you exactly mean by nearest matching person?

Comment: Basically the person that has the closest attribute scores to what you search.. Thinking about it I'm not actually sure this is possible with this kind of schema

Comment: Post your desired result with explanation.

Comment: You can calculate a measure like 'Minkowski' distance or 'Manhattan' distance to find similar users based on their scores. I assume the users have to compared on each attribute.

Comment: Using the words "*most efficient way*" to describe an operation on an Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model strikes me as an oxymoron.

Comment: Would you suggestion be to denormalise then? Happy to do so if it's not going to be achievable with EAV schema

Comment: Do you want like the difference in each attribute? Total attribute values? What are your expected results?

Answer (score 0):

To transpose this table directly you can use the following query:

```
create table data_transpose as
select person
    , case when attribute_id = 1 then value else null end as attribute_1
    , case when attribute_id = 2 then value else null end as attribute_2
    , case when attribute_id = 3 then value else null end as attribute_3
    , case when attribute_id = 4 then value else null end as attribute_4
 ;
```

As far as nearest matching goes you can choose between a lot of distance/similarity measures.  You may wish to consider euclidean and cosine similarity measures among others. To perform cosine similarity (which has better properties for what you are doing I think) use below, assuming your data is like:

```
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|person | attribute_1  | attribute_2 | attribute_3 |person2| attribute_1_2 | attribute_2_2 | attribute_3_2 |
|1      | 4            | 2           | 0           |2      | 0             | 5             | 5             |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

You can calculate cosine similarity as below after a cross join or some other join creating the above table :

```
select person
, person2
,  (attribute_1 * attribute_1_2 + attribute_2 * attribute_2_2 + attribute_3 * attribute_3_2 + attribute_4 * attribute_4_2)/
    (
    sqrt(pow(abs(attribute_1),2) + pow(abs(attribute_2),2) + pow(abs(attribute_3),2) + pow(abs(attribute_3),2) + pow(abs(attribute_4),2))
   *
    sqrt(pow(abs(attribute_1-2),2) + pow(abs(attribute_2_2),2) + pow(abs(attribute_3_2),2) + pow(abs(attribute_3_2),2) + pow(abs(attribute_4_2),2))
    ) as cosine_similarity
from
some_join_of_transposed_table_here
;
```

The code here is not debugged code.  Good luck.